# GWT SinkEvent is not working except on firefox

Tags: java, gwt, browser, onclicklistener

I am trying to sink an event on anchor element which is inside `<li>` and the listeners on the `<li>` is just working fine but it's not working on the anchors on any other element. 
The weird thing that it's working on `FireFox` only

The html output is something like:

```xml
<li>
    Some Text
</li> 
<li>
    Some Text<a class='myClass'>Anchor</a>
</li>
```

**JAVA Code for the listener**

```
this.eventListener = new EventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onBrowserEvent(Event e) {
            Element elem = e.getTarget();

            //This means we want to use the option selection 
            switch (e.getTypeInt()) {
                case Event.ONCLICK:

                    if (LIElement.is(elem) && !elem.hasClassName('myClass')) {
                        selectOption((LIElement) elem);
                    } else {
                        LIElement li = (LIElement) elem.getParentElement();
                        createContact(li);
                    }

                    break;
                case Event.ONMOUSEOVER:
                    //do something

                    break;
                case Event.ONMOUSEOUT:
                   //do something
                    break;
            }

        }//End of onBrowserEvent 
    };//End of event listener
```

I am using this to create elements:

```
LIElement li = Document.get().createLIElement();
AnchorElement createContactLI = Document.get().createAnchorElement();
createContactLI.addClassName(NEW_CONTACT_CLASS);
createContactLI.setInnerText("Add new contact");
createContactLI.setId("myID");
li.appendChild(createContactLI); 
ulPanel.appendChild(li);
```

This to sink events:

```
Event.sinkEvents(ulPanel, Event.ONCLICK | Event.ONMOUSEOVER | Event.ONMOUSEOUT);
Event.setEventListener(ulPanel, this.eventListener);`
```

**What I tried**

- Sinked the event of the anchor , DID NOT WOK
- Wrap the anchorElement in anchor and added ClickHandler , Didn't work
- Converting the anchorElement to liElement , Didn't work
- BTW Break points is not fired when dealing with the anchorElement
- Also tried CSS and z-indexing , Didn't work

**What I am going to do**
 - Write the whole feature as widgets , which will take me a long time

Your help is really really really appreciated

Comment: I think you may need to make add a specific event handler to the anchor element. And in the anchor element event listener call. event.preventDefault(). Otherwise the browser will automatically handle the default anchor click. The anchor element may be capturing the click event and not propagating the event to your ulPanel. I know what you are doing may work but it I have had problems with this in the past and decided to add the handler to the li element itself rather than the container.

Comment: @ChrisHinshaw thanks for your comment, that look logical to me.
BTW I did what you are doing now and using the handlers to element itself and the propagation i stopped it when clicking the anchor :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `com.google.gwt.user.client.Element` use `com.google.gwt.dom.client.Element`. I don't know where exactly you are adding your `ulPanel` to. But the following code worked:

```
import com.google.gwt.dom.client.AnchorElement;
import com.google.gwt.dom.client.DivElement;
import com.google.gwt.dom.client.Document;
import com.google.gwt.dom.client.Element;
import com.google.gwt.dom.client.EventTarget;
import com.google.gwt.dom.client.LIElement;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.Event;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.EventListener;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.Window;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.VerticalPanel;

public class CustomWidget extends VerticalPanel{

    public CustomWidget() {
        DivElement ulPanel = Document.get().createDivElement();
        LIElement li = Document.get().createLIElement();
        AnchorElement createContactLI = Document.get().createAnchorElement();
        createContactLI.addClassName("myclass");
        createContactLI.setInnerText("Add new contact");
        createContactLI.setId("myID");
        li.appendChild(createContactLI); 
        ulPanel.appendChild(li); 

        Event.sinkEvents(ulPanel, Event.ONCLICK | Event.ONMOUSEOVER | Event.ONMOUSEOUT);
        Event.setEventListener(ulPanel, this.eventListener);

        this.getElement().appendChild(ulPanel);
    }

    EventListener eventListener = new EventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onBrowserEvent(Event e) {
            //This means we want to use the option selection 
            switch (e.getTypeInt()) {
                case Event.ONCLICK:
                    EventTarget eventTarget = e.getEventTarget();
                    Element elem = Element.as(eventTarget);
                    if (AnchorElement.is(elem) && "myclass".equals(elem.getAttribute("class"))) {
                        Window.alert("clicked anchor element");
                    } else {
                        LIElement li = (LIElement) elem.getParentElement();
                        Window.alert("clicked li element");
                    }

                    break;
                case Event.ONMOUSEOVER:
                    //do something

                    break;
                case Event.ONMOUSEOUT:
                   //do something
                    break;
            }

        }//End of onBrowserEvent 
    };//End of event listener 

}
```

Comment: But why , what is your explanation ?
BTW I didn't test this yet

Answer (score 0):

Try to initialize you code in onLoad() widget life cycle method.

```
@Override
      protected void onLoad() {
    radioButton = DOM.getElementById("radio_green_id_1").cast();
    radioButton.setId(DOM.createUniqueId());

Event.sinkEvents(ulPanel, Event.ONCLICK | Event.ONMOUSEOVER | Event.ONMOUSEOUT);
Event.setEventListener(ulPanel, this.eventListener);

      }
```